# Concatenating Multiple Javascript Objects Into One Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, orgchart

I am trying to add javascript objects all into one variable, but not within the same object. Here is what I mean:

```
object1 = {id: 1, name: Dean};
object2 = {id: 2, name: Sam};
object3 = {id: 3, name: Castiel};
```

I need them to be:

```
object1 = {id: 1, name: Dean}, {id: 2, name: Sam}, {id: 3, name: Castiel};
```

I am currently retrieving all this information back from an ajax call and need to loop through it and return it in a valid javascript object and pass all these objects at once to a variable:

```
var hierarchy;
for (i = 0; i < response['tree']['id'].length; i++) {

    hierarchy = $.extend(true, hierarchy, {
        id: response['tree']['id'][i],
        parentId: response['tree']['parentId'][i], 
        Name: response['tree']['name'][i]
    });
}

var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("cast"), {
    dataSource: [hierarchy]
});
```

Primary objective: The dataSource property needs to end up with values that look like so:

```
var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("cast"), {
    dataSource: [{id: 1, name: Dean}, {id: 2, name: Sam}, {id: 3, name: Castiel}]
});
```

**EDIT: SOLUTION**, Based on answers provided, I modified the code and now it works correctly, I misunderstood what the console log was outputting vs what syntax was allowable.

```
var hierarchy = [];
for (i = 1;i < response['tree']['id'].length; i++) {

    groupData = {
        id: response['tree']['id'][i],
        parentId: response['tree']['parentId'][i], 
        Name: response['tree']['name'][i]
    };

    hierarchy.push(groupData);
}

var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("cast"), {
    dataSource: [{
        id: response['tree']['id'][0],
        parentId: response['tree']['parentId'][0], 
        Name: response['tree']['name'][0]
    }]
});

orgchart.loadFromJSON(hierarchy);
```

Comment: `object1 = {id: 1, name: Dean}, {id: 2, name: Sam}, {id: 3, name: Castiel};`this is invalid JS. You could `objectArray = [{id: 1, name: Dean}, {id: 2, name: Sam}, {id: 3, name: Castiel}];` . Please note that it is an Array [] of Objects now. One can use `push()` into Array. Assuming your Data from AJAX is data something like `response.data.forEach((elem) => ObjectArray.push(elem))` in pseudo.

Comment: use Object.Assing https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: This is impossible. You need to use either an `Array` (type of object) or a generic `Object`. JavaScript variables can't hold multiple values.

Comment: @P.Waksman English link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @Tyler thanks, didn't notice that wasn't in English

Comment: @P.Waksman :P, if you want to update your comment. Immediately after the "org" in the link, you have `/pt-BR`. Just need to change that to `/en-US`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to point out that the code below is invalid.

```
object1 = {id: 1, name: Dean}, {id: 2, name: Sam}, {id: 3, name: Castiel};
```

You should use an array to hold those values, that will look like this:

```
const objects = [{id: 1, name: Dean}, {id: 2, name: Sam}, {id: 3, name: Castiel}];
```

Note: You will be able to add new objects into the array using `push()`.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my answer based on the help you provided in clarifying this for me. I was mixing up the console log output with correct javascript syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Since I like the show

```
var parent = { objectOne: { id: 1, name: 'Dean' },  objectTwo: { id: 2, name: 'Sam' },  object3: { id: 3, name: 'Castiel' } }
```

Or as an array

```
var parent = [{ id: 1, name: 'Dean' }, { id: 2, name: 'Sam' }, { id: 3, name: 'Castiel' } ]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Your current **I need them to be:** requirement is **not valid** with Javascript.

```
object1 = {id: 1, name: Dean}, {id: 2, name: Sam}, {id: 3, name: Castiel};
```

You've can try with this way,

```js
var obj = {
  object1: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Dean'
  },
  object2: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Sam'
  },
  object3: {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Castiel'
  }
};

var allObj = [];

// Populate allObj array
for (var key in obj) {
  allObj.push(obj[key]);
}
console.log(allObj);
```